# jQuery checking dynamically created checkboxes/radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form that has dynamically created checkboxes. The checkboxes are stored in the database. Some of the checkboxes can have child items. These will be displayed as soon as we check the checkbox. Check example below
[image]

The code for generating these is

```
function DrawMinorCaseFileCheckboxList() {
var result = "";
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "UACWebServices.asmx/GetMinorCaseFileTree",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
        var parentDivData = '<div class="container">';
        var iii = 0;
        $.each(obj.children, function (i, parentItem) {
            //parentDivData = parentItem.children && parentItem.children.length > 0 ? parentDivData += '<span></span>' : parentDivData
            //if (parentItem.children && parentItem.children.length > 0) {
            //    parentDivData += '<ul style="list-style:none;margin:0;" ><li><input type="checkbox" id="' + parentItem.id + '" class="minor-casefile-info"><label for="option"><strong>' + parentItem.text + '</strong></label>';
            //}
            //else {
            //    parentDivData += '<ul style="list-style:none;margin:0;" ><li><input type="checkbox" id="' + parentItem.id + '" class="minor-casefile-info"><label for="option">' + parentItem.text + '</label>';
            //}

            parentDivData += '<ul class="spCasefileSummaries" style="list-style:none;margin:0;" ><li><input type="checkbox" name="spCasefileSummaries_' + parentItem.id + '" id="spCasefileSummaries_' + parentItem.id + '" idd="' + parentItem.id + '" txt="' + parentItem.text+'" class="minor-casefile-info" > <label for="option">' + parentItem.text + '</label>';
            
            if (parentItem.children && parentItem.children.length > 0) {
                parentDivData += '<ul style="list-style:none;display:none;padding-inline:20px;" ulParentID=' + parentItem.id +'>';
                $.each(parentItem.children, function (i, childItem) {
                    parentDivData += '<li><label><input type="radio" parentId="radiobutton_' + parentItem.id + '" id="minor-casefile-info_' + childItem.id + '" name="minor-casefile-info_' + parentItem.id + '"  value="' + childItem.id +'" class="minor-casefile-info-sub' + parentItem.id + '"> ' + childItem.text + '</label></li>';
                });
                parentDivData += '</ul>';
            }
            parentDivData += '</li></ul>';
            iii++;
        });
        parentDivData += '</div>';
        
        $('#dCaseFile').html(parentDivData);

        $('.minor-casefile-info').change(function () {
            var str = '';
            var id = $(this).attr("idd");
            //console.log($(this));
            //console.log($(this).attr("txt"));

            if (this.checked) {
                $('[ulParentID=' + id + ']').show();
            }
            else {   
                $('[ulParentID=' + id + ']').hide();
                $('[parentId = radiobutton_' + id + ']').prop("checked", false);
                $("#tbCaseFile").valid();
            }
            $(".minor-casefile-info").each(function (i, obj) {
                var headerTitle = $(this).attr("txt");
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    if ($("[parentid = radiobutton_" + $(this).attr("idd") + "]").length > 0) {
                        str += 'Please select a description of the ' + headerTitle + '<br/>';
                    }
                }
            });
            if (str) {
                $('.trCaseFileInfoMessage').show();
                $('#sCaseFileInfoMessage').html(str);
            }
            else {
                $('.trCaseFileInfoMessage').hide();
                $('#sCaseFileInfoMessage').html('');
            }
        });
    }
});
   }
```

This is all working fine. When I save the data and come back to the page by clicking Edit I need to populate all the fields on the page that were saved. In my code behind (.cs) I have a function that loads the data from the database and prepopulates all the fields. For the dynamic checkboxes I am calling a JS function to check the checkboxes and radiobuttons but they are coming as undefined

The .cs method calling the js function

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "populateCaseFileSummaries", "populateCaseFileSummaries('" + LIST_Minor_Casefile_Info + "', '" + LIST_Minor_Casefile_Info_Sub + "');", true);
```

and the js function

```
function populateCaseFileSummaries(parentCheckbox, childRadioBtn) {
var parentItems = parentCheckbox.split(",");
console.log('parentItems = ' + parentItems);
$.each(parentItems, function (index, value) {
    $("#spCasefileSummaries_" + value).prop("checked", true);
    //document.getElementById('spCasefileSummaries_' + value).checked = true;
    console.log('parent: - ' + '#spCasefileSummaries_' + value);
    console.log('isChecked: ' + $('#spCasefileSummaries_' + value).prop('checked'));
});
var childItems = childRadioBtn.split(",");
$.each(childItems, function (index, value) {
    console.log('Child: - ' + value);
});
}
```

Here is the console logs

[image]

Can someone please tell me how I can access these checkboxes and radiobuttons? Thanks

Comment: Hi, what does `parentCheckbox` &  `childRadioBtn` has in it ? Can you show output of that ?

Comment: In the database we are saving the parent checkbox ids that were checked as a comma-separated list. So the data can be 1,3 and child radio buttons will be 2,6. They are the ids of the parents and the child and they are all unique

Comment: Also, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gtpfzv62/) might help .Make sure your DOM is loaded when you called your functions to checked.

Comment: yes that was the issue but I managed to get it to work using hidden fields. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work by using a hidden field. I set the hidden field value to the checkboxes and radiobutton ids and used them after the DOM loaded and enabled the checkboxes.

Thanks